# cycle "for" in Python

Tags: python

I have to create a three new lists of items using two different lists.

```
list_one = ['one', 'two','three', 'four','five']
list_two = ['blue', 'green', 'white']
```

So, `len(list_one) != len(list_two)`

Now I should create an algorithm(a cycle) which can do this: 
`[oneblue, twoblue, threeblue, fourblue, fiveblue]`. Same for 'green' and 'white'.

I undestand that I should create three cycles but I don't know how.
I've tried to make a function like this but it doesn't works.

```
def mix():
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(list_one)):
        new_list = list_one[i]+list_two[0]
        i = i+1
        return new_list
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* - You are returning inside the loop, preventing any iteration beside the first to be executed. - You are returning `new_list`, but if you look at it you'll see it is just a string. - You are incrementing `i`, which is the role of the range. - you assume you need 3 cycles, but I don't see where you got that idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> [b + a for a,b in itertools.product(list_two, list_one)]
['oneblue',
 'twoblue',
 'threeblue',
 'fourblue',
 'fiveblue',
 'onegreen',
 'twogreen',
 'threegreen',
 'fourgreen',
 'fivegreen',
 'onewhite',
 'twowhite',
 'threewhite',
 'fourwhite',
 'fivewhite']
```

Comment: Why the inversion? :) `[a + b for a,b in itertools.product(list_one, list_two)]`

Answer (score 0):

- return should be out of for loop.
- No need to initialize `i` and increment it, since you are using range.
- Also, since both list can be of variable length, don't use range. Iterate over the list elements directly.
- `def mix():` should be like `def mix(l_one,l_two):`

All above in below code:

```
def mix(l_one,l_two):
    new_list = []
    for x in l_one:
        for y in l_two:
            new_list.append(x+y)
    return new_list

list_one = ['one', 'two','three', 'four','five']
list_two = ['blue', 'green', 'white']
n_list = mix(list_one,list_two)
print n_list
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
['oneblue', 'onegreen', 'onewhite', 'twoblue', 'twogreen', 'twowhite', 'threeblu
e', 'threegreen', 'threewhite', 'fourblue', 'fourgreen', 'fourwhite', 'fiveblue'
, 'fivegreen', 'fivewhite']

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Using List Comprehension, `mix()` function will look like below:

```
   def mix(l_one,l_two):
          new_list =[x+y for x in l_one for y in l_two]
          return new_list
```

Comment: great answer but the result should be ['oneblue', 'twoblue', 'threeblue', ..., 'fivewhite']

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
def cycle(list_one,list_two):
   newList = []
   for el1 in list_two:
      for el2 in list_one:
         newList.append(el2+el1)
   return newList
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. When you do a for loop `for i in ...:`, you do not need to initialize `i` (`i = 0`) and you should not increment it (`i = i + 1`) since Python knows that `i` will take all values specified in the for loop definition.
2. If your code indentation (indentation is very important in Python) is truly the one written above, your `return` statement is inside the for loop. As soon as your function encounters your return statement, your function will exit and return what you specified: in this case, a string.
3. `new_list` is not a list but a string.
4. In Python, you can loop directly over the list items as opposed to their index (`for item in list_one:` as opposed to `for i in range(len(list_one)):`

Here is your code cleaned up:

```
def mix():
    new_list = []
    for i in list_one:
        new_list.append(list_one[i]+list_two[0])
    return new_list
```

This can be rewritten using a list comprehension:

```
def mix(list_one, list_two):
    return [item+list_two[0] for item in list_one]
```

And because `list_two` has more than one item, you would need to iterate over `list_two` as well:

```
def mix(list_one, list_two):
    return [item+item2 for item in list_one for item2 in list_two]
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    [a+b for a in list_one for b in list_two]
```

and

[[a+b for a in list_one] for b in list_two]